# how to develop MFP8.0 web application with ionic3

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ionic3

I have developed hybride application with MFP 8.0 and Ionic3. Working fine in android and ios. Now i want use same code to run on MFP 8.0 with web. i have created sample project but my doubt is how to deploy same code in web

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Web application using the same code base. To this you can add IBM MFP Web SDK which provides you APIs and features to access MFP server and through it, your backend.

Note that the web application itself will be hosted on your web server or node server ( or any mechanism of your choice). The web SDK will allow the API calls to flow into MFP server.

Refer to the tutorial [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/web/) , for documentation and [samples](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/quick-start/web/).

Comment: HI Vivin,Thanks for update, You mean, we have to install MFP web sdk with help of "npm install ibm-mfp-web-sdk" and need to    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/ibm-mfp-web-sdk/ibmmfpf.js"></script>mpf.js file in header section for ionic project right??